# Javascript regex for currency format

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, currency

Suppose I have an unknown price format, that can be

**12345.00 USD**

**123.00 XXX**

**anyOtherString**

..and I need to have

**12345.00 USD** ==> *$12345*

**12345 00 USD** ==> *$123*

**123.00 XXX** ==> *123.00 XXX*

**anyOtherString** ==> *anyOtherString*

How would you approach this?

## EDIT

Testing with the following:

```js
var str1 = "122.00 USD";
console.log("str1: "+str1.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2'));
// ==> $122

var str2 = "122 00 USD";
console.log("str2: "+str2.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2'));
// ==> $122

var str3 = "122 USD";
console.log("str3: "+str3.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2'));
// ==> $122

var str4 = "122";
console.log("str4: "+str4.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2'));
// ==> 122

var str5 = "122.00";
console.log("str5: "+str5.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2'));
// ==> 122.00

var str6 = "$122";
console.log("str6: "+str6.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2'));
// ==> $122
```

..and it's almost OK, except for **str4** and **str5** that gave a wrong result

Comment: I would start by reading some good tutorials on regular expressions, ie http://www.regexone.com. Then, I would try some code on my own. And then, when I got stuck eventually, I'd come back here and ask a good question with code samples and the (failed) tries in it.

Comment: Is the fractional part of the number always 0 ? Or can you have something like 123.50 USD ?

Comment: If it's "123.50 USD" I'd like to keep it like it is, so "123.50 USD".
I just need to convert it to "$123" in these cases:"
- "123.00 USD"
- "123 00 USD"
- "123.00"
- "123 00"

All other cases should be left as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit : The correct answer is in the edit part, below*
Here is something that works for every case I could think about :
Replace :
`(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD`
by
`$\1\2`
However, if there is a missing point between in a non integer number, it doesn't work. For instance, `123 456` USD will be replaced by `123 $456`
Also, I couldn't find a way to let numbers like "123.456 USD" untouched (see comments below)
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ngWwDE/4)
I can provide more details if you need any explanation.
If you see some cases I didn't handle, just say it !
Code for Javascript :

```js
var str = '123.00 USD 1234 USD 357.0 USD 456 00 USD 651USD 753.684 USD 123 456 USD -123 USD 789.00 XXX 123.00 wrongcurrency test string $159';
str = str.replace(/(\d+)(?:(?:[\.\s]0+|(\.\d+)))?\s?USD/g, '$$$1$2');
console.log(str);
```

---

**EDIT :**

Ok I think I got it. Correct me if I am wrong :
Your string is composed by a single number, possibly with a fractional part separated by either a dot or a space. The number may be followed by an other string.
If the fractional part of this number doesn't exist, or equals 0, and this number is followed by USD or nothing, you want to replace it by the same value with a `$` at the beginning. Otherwise, you do nothing.
If this is what you're looking for, I can give you exactly what you want (it is far more simple than multiple numbers in the same string ^^).
`123`, `123.00`, `123 USD`, `123 00 USD` and `-123 00`have to be matched and replaced for example
You just have to replace :
`^(-)?(\d+)(?:[\s\.]0+)?\s*(?:USD)?$`
by
`\1$\2`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/MJTGJk/2)
Code for Javascript :

```js
var strArray = ['123.00 USD', '1234 USD', '357.0 USD', '456 00 USD', '651USD', '753.684 USD', '123 456 USD', '-123 USD', '789.00 XXX', '123.00 wrongcurrency', 'test string', '$159', '123'];
var strReplaced = "";
for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; ++i) {
  strReplaced = strArray[i].replace(/^(-)?(\d+)(?:[\s\.]0+)?\s*(?:USD)?$/g, '$1$$$2');
  console.log(strArray[i]+" => "+strReplaced);
}
```

Comment: I'm facing a wall right now... I don't see how to do that with regex in Javascript. Either the case "123 USD" won't be treated, or the case "123.456 USD" will be treated. I can't make "123 USD" treated AND "123.456 USD" untouched

Comment: edited my question, you can see there what I've tried to do. thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what str4 and str5 should return... If I read correctly, only numbers followed by USD should be replaced. Am I wrong ? You mean any number alone should be replaced by the $ version ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, tell me if this is better for you

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try the following

([$*\s]*(?:\d{1,3}(?:[\s,]\d{3})+|\d+)(?:.\d{2})?([\s]*[a-z-A-Z]{0,3}))

example :https://regex101.com/r/ngWwDE/2